# Any way to not have to include CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in every ToString call?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

ReSharper always gets mad at me if I don't specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or some other culture in each of my ToString calls. The application is currently only in English but looking towards the future is always good. Is there any way to specify an application setting so all `ToString` calls by default use `InvariantCulture`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way... create an extension method

```cs
public static string MyToString(this int x)
{
    return x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Give it a better name though :)

Comment: Also, the parameter should be a numeric type -- there's no such overload on System.String.